# vba to save xltm file as xlsb file

Tags: excel, vba, save-as, xlsb

I have a script which opens an external file to execute a script and after finishing the script, it saves as an xlsb file. The code worked perfectly for saving from xlsb file to xlsb file. But because I want to have some security for the original file, I want the original xlsb file to be a xltm file. I adapted the save as script to it and tested it as a separate routine in the file itself. It works perfectly.

Now I added the routine to the external script file, but when I execute the script then, Excel freezes and no 'save as' screen appears at all. 
I expect the external script to have some other external reference to work properly but I cannot figure out how to adjust my script to this.

This is the code of the *original file*:

```
Option Explicit
Sub vernieuwalles()
Dim myTemplate As String: myTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim myTool As String: myTool = "refresh_segment_template.xlsm"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Workbooks.Open GetPath & myTool
  Application.Run myTool & "!vernieuwalles", myTemplate

  Call Windows(myTool).Close(False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Private Function GetPath() As String
Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition

  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\XLAM\"

End Function
```

It refers to the *external script* file to be opened and executed.

The *external* file has this script (I only pasted the save as part of the script):

```
Option Explicit

Dim aantalrijen As Long

Const SheetSchaduwblad As String = "schaduwblad"
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

  Application.StatusBar = "Bezig met vernieuwen"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen

  Call datawissen
  Call dataplaatsen
  Call kolomtitels
  Call toevoegen
  Call maaktabel
  Call refreshpivots

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Sub refreshpivots()
Dim workbook_Name As Variant
Dim location As String
Dim workbookdirectory As String
Dim activewb As String

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

activewb = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

workbookdirectory = "M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\"

workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:=workbookdirectory & activewb)

If workbook_Name = False Then

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=activewb, FileFormat:=50

End If
```

But when I execute the script from the *original* file, excel freezes as pointed out. What should be changed for this code to be working with the external file and the save from xltm to xlsb script?

As pointed out: the save as script is the only thing that has changed *in the script*  and the xlsb to xltm extension-change is the only thing that has changed in the *original file*.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=activewb, FileFormat:=50` Debug this line and check what is the value of `activewb`

Comment: I changed activewb to mytemplate.name (mytemplate is the original file) as it is referred to in the script and tried to execute the script again. But still excel freezes.

Comment: I have run into this as well with projects im working on and I found that adding `DoEvents` before and/or after the save event seemed to help.  The `DoEvents` allows Excel to complete what its doing before the save event and got rid of the freezing issue i ran into.

Comment: Where do you suggest I should add that doevents in the script?
However, I suspect the activewb.name or mytemplate.name part to be the problem as it might not be able to read the filename of the source file the way I made the script?